# Is there any other solution to the integral equation $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{kx}f(x) dx=\frac{k^2+k}{k^3},k<0$ except $f(x)=x-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, integral-equations

Is there any other solution to the integral equation $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{kx}f(x) dx=\frac{k^2+k}{k^3},k<0$$ except $f(x)=x-1$?

Comment: Laplace Transform pairs are unique

Comment: Note one can always "create" an integrable function different from $f(x) = x - 1$ which is the solution to the integral equation by making its values larger for certain regions of $x$, but correspondingly smaller in other regions of $x$ to compensate. Thus, you should specify any specific qualities (e.g., differentiable, expressing in terms of elementary functions, etc.) you specifically want $f(x)$ to have. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan $f(x)$ should be bounded and measurable.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I think OP wants the equation to be satisfied for every $k<0$. In that case what Mark Viola says in his comment is true. The manipulation you suggest is possible for  a fixed $k$ but not for all $k<0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, well said.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your suggestion. That makes sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I meant it for every $k<0$ and I think Mark Viola has answered it. But my question is more general actually, here it was a coincidence that my integral is a Laplace transform which I didn't notice before posting. I will be posting a similar question in a new post.